# Working solution for adding header or footer view to Endless Adapter

Tags: android, listview, commonsware-cwac

i'm searching for a solution for adding header / footer views to Endless Adapter. I've done many tries but with no luck.
Can someone post a simple working code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would expect an `EndlessAdapter` wrapped around a `MergeAdapter` would work for headers added via the `MergeAdapter`. Footers, though, you cannot use with `EndlessAdapter`, period, as the footer would mess up `EndlessAdapter`'s "we got to the end" logic. You would need to create your own "endless" solution for that.

Note that this refers to headers and footers that are designed to scroll with the contents. If you want *fixed* headers and footers, those are simply views outside the `ListView`, using a vertical `LinearLayout` or something to sequence them appropriately.